# Powershell - Check if Value in CSV exists

Tags: powershell

I want to check if a string exists in a csv file.

I'm trying to use `if ($PCname -in $logFileLocation) { write-output "true" } else { write-output "false" }`

However this always returns false.

How can I check for a value within a csv file?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how `$logFileLocation` is populated, in relation to your CSV file; best to include some sample data. Also, is your intent only to look only in  a _given column_ of your CSV data, or across all columns?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with your approach given that `$logFileLocation` contains the column where the property lies.

Comment: -in only matches whole array elements (lines probably in your case), similar to -contains

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate a query within the result of dir ( `Get-Childitem` )

```
$Query = "yourString"
$List = Get-Childitem *.CSV |
Select-Object Name,@{Name="MatchesQuery"; Expression={($_ | Get-Content -raw) -match $Query}}
$List
```

Attention: `$Query` will be interpreted as regular expression

That way you get a list of all files with the information that it is matching your cirteria or not. That way you can filter afterwards like that:

`$List | where {$_.MatchesQuery -eq $true}`

Depending in your CSV it might be better and more relyable if you do not only `Get-Content` but use `ConvertFrom-CSV` and select the column you want to search in.

This version reads CSV and searches the column "ComputerName" for your `$Query`

```
$Query = "yourString"
$List = Get-Childitem *.CSV | Select-Object Name,@{Name="MatchesQuery"; Expression={($_ | Get-Content -raw | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter ";" | where {$_.ComputerName -eq "$Query").Count -gt 0}}}
$List
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be helpful:

```
$find = "some_string"
Get-Content C:\temp\demo.csv | Select-String $find
```